# Has there any official background story of Miku? Is she human or android?

Tags: hatsune-miku

There's a manga titled *Hatsune Miku: Unofficial Hatsune Mix* written and illustrated by the original artist. However, it is said that it is not official (I haven't read it).

Has there ever any official background story about Miku? It doesn't have to be like any kind of manga, just a background story of her or her personality. All I know (from wiki) is that Hatsune Miku is a 16-year-old girl (or android).

I know Miku is a vocaloid, means she's a software. But as a character is she human or not?

Comment: in the 3 [Visual Novels by Supplement Time](https://vndb.org/c4545) list her as a robot as her Role. on the same page her other appearances her role is listed as High School Student, Senpai and Singer (which to be honest don't mean too much in determining between human and machine)